# Inheritance bug in PHP

Tags: php

Just found out that there is a bug in OOP inheritance in PHP. In the code below:

```
class A {
    public $attribute1;
    public function operation1() {
        echo "calling operation1()<br>";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public $attribute2;
    public function operation2() {
        echo "calling operation2()<br>";
    }
}


$b = new B();
$b->operation2();

$a = new A();
$a->attribute2 = 10;
echo '$a->attribute2 = ' . $a->attribute2;
$a->operation2();
```

$a->attribute2 = 10; is working! But it should not, as A also does not have an $arrtibute2(supeclass cannot access subclass' arrtibutes and methods!)

I believe this is a language bug, but I once saw people using this 'bug' to write code!

Comment: `A` does not have an `operation2()`

Comment: You are initializing a new property `$attribute2` in `A` at the moment you assign it. That is known and understood behavior (not a bug).

Comment: Run this code with error reporting turned all the way up and `display_errors` enabled.  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: http://3v4l.org/TYWil It will produce a fatal error when you call `$a->operation2()`

Comment: A also does not have an $arrtibute2, but it works in PHP!

Comment: @user305611156 That is expected behavior. PHP allows you to create any new attribute implicitly just by assigning it (with public visibility). Attributes don't need to be explicitly defined in the class definition.

Comment: @Michael Berkowski, is there any official statement about this behavior? Such a behavior, in my opinion, violates the principle of OOP, you definitely could not do it in Java or C#

Comment: @user305611156 I've been searching for it... PHP's class property rules [are documented here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php) but I have been digging for where it explicitly mentions the implicit creation. If I ever find it, I'll link it here.

Comment: The closest thing I've been able to find is this mention of it as a `ZEND_ACC_IMPLICIT_PUBLIC`, which is little more than an [acknowledgement that it's a thing](https://wiki.php.net/internals/engine/objects).

Comment: By the way, there's quite a lot about PHP's class implementation that would infuriate a Java dev.

Comment: The proposed PHP spec touches upon these in [Dynamic Members](https://github.com/php/php-langspec/blob/master/spec/14-classes.md#dynamic-members), mostly as an afterthought at the end of describing dynamic properties explicitly handled by `__set` and `__get`.